# Can not Post Array of object to web api in swift 4.0

Tags: json, swift, post, webapi

Swift Code:

```
func set(data:[AirFreightModel],userid:String,username:String,completion:@escaping(Result<String,CustomError>)->Void)
{
    let url = URL(string: "\(CS.ServerName)/AirFreight/SetAirFreightApproval?UserID=\(userid)&UserName=\(username)")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    //request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    do{
        let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)
        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(jsonString)

        let parameters: [String: String] = [
            "AirFreight": jsonString
        ]
        //request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data,
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                error == nil else {                                              // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
                    return
            }

            guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                return
            }

            do{
                let decoder=JSONDecoder()
                let userResponse=try decoder.decode(String.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(userResponse))
            }catch
            {
                print("Unexpected  error: \(error)")
                completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    catch
    {

    }

}
```

Web Api Code:

```
public string SetAirFreightApproval(List<AirFreightModel> AirFreight,string UserID,String UserName)
{
return "1";
}
```

The request to web api is made perfectly so the QueryString variable data passing working ok, but the Array of object  data can not be passed. I am new in Swift so don't know what am i messing around. I am using Swift 4.2. and xcode 10. 
Sample JSON String:

```
[
  {
    "CauseID": " Matha Nosto Man",
    "CompanyName": "",
    "RaciActionList": [

    ],
    "PoType": "",
    "CauseDescription": "",
    "FBID": "Test",
    "ResponseResult": "",
    "RACI": "",
    "Destination": "",
    "Remarks": "",
    "Sequence": "",
    "Type": "",
    "BillDate": "",
    "FreightType": "",
    "BillAmount": "",
    "BillRef": "",
    "CommandName": "",
    "IsChecked": false,
    "EmployeeCode": "",
    "BuyerORExporter": "",
    "Mode": "",
    "Forwarder": "",
    "RunningFor": ""
  }
]
```

TIA
[image: Web Api Request]

Where shows the request to web api has been made perfactly as the rest parameters get all values accept the List one.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the "Sample JSON String:"? The desired output? Your current output in Swift? From where did you print it exactly? There is bad code in your code, and also, you are saying the params are url-encoded, but send JSON?

Comment: No, This is what I am try to send to Web Api.  If you look into my code you can see there is a print statement from where I get this JSON String. Which I try to send to Web Api Server. There might be any bad code in my code as i told I am very new in swift, so most of my code is from the internet, can you point me out which one is inappropiate?

Answer (score 0):

If Web API expects JSON in body (as I would expect), then preparing request should be like following (typed directly here, so might be typos)

```
let parameters = [
    "AirFreight": data
]
// options by default [], so can be dropped
request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters) 
// your can print debug of request.httpBody after serialisation to check
```

this will send complete JSON object,

```
{
   "AirFreight": [
     {
       "CauseID": " Matha Nosto Man",
       "CompanyName": "",
       "RaciActionList": [

        ],
        "PoType": "",
        ...
   ]
}
```

opposite to provided your code snapshot which generates one item-JSON, like (scratchy)

```
{
   "AirFreight": "Very long flat string containing all objects properties"
}
```

Comment: i think let parameters: [String: String] = [
            "AirFreight": jsonString
        ]
and let parameters= [
            "AirFreight": jsonString
        ]  both are same statement one is explicitly defining the data type another is implicit.